# Custom block service not found by Sonata

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am  having a weird situation which has halted my progress for the second day now and I am almost going bald from pulling my hair on this. I have a custom block on the sonata admin dashboard which is not being found when I try to load the page.

I have gone over the configuration a couple of times and maybe I am missing something which an extra pair of eyes may be able to spot which is why I am posting this question here.

I have built my block as below and saved it under src\AppBundle\Block\NumbersBlockService.php

```
namespace   AppBundle\Block;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BaseBlockService;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql;

class NumbersBlockService extends BaseBlockService
{
    ......
}
```

Then defined my service in the service.yml file as below:

```
sonata.block.service.topnumbers:
        class: AppBundle\Block\NumbersBlockService
        arguments:
            -   sonata.block.service.topnumbers
            -   "@templating"
            -   "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            -   "@security.token_storage"
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.block }
```

My config.yml file includes the block like this

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)
        sonata.block.service.text: # used to if you plan to use Sonata user routes
        sonata.block.service.topnumbers:
```

and finally, I position the block on top with the line below

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            - { position: top, type: sonata.block.service.topnumbers, class: col-md-12}
```

I have checked the tutorial on creating a custom block here https://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/your_first_block.html and everything seems to check out but I still get the following error below:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The block type "sonata.block.service.topnumbers" does not exist") in SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig at line 60.
```

Someone please help put me out of my misery. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you declare your service.yml in your config ? With - { resource: "@YourBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

Comment: Yes I have. It has some services declared there which are working well  except this one